# how to set tooltip on asp boundfield datafield hedertext inside of gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have grid view.there are two BoundField.here i want to set tooltip on BoundField  DataField HeaderText **Topic**.

code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Dgvlist" runat="server" >
  <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField  DataField="topic"  HeaderText="Topic"  />
   <asp:BoundField DataField="question" HeaderText="Question"  /> 
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

there are any solution?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 usual ways to set tooltip on `BoundField` column:

**1) Using code-behind `RowDataBound` event**

```
protected void Dgvlist_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        e.Row.Cells[0].ToolTip = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Topic", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

**2) Using code-behind `RowCreated` event**

```
protected void Dgvlist_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableRow row in Dgvlist.Controls[0].Controls)
    {
        row.Cells[0].ToolTip = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Topic", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

**3) Convert to `TemplateField` and use `Label` control**

```
<asp:GridView ID="Dgvlist" runat="server" ...>
  <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Topic">
       <asp:Label ID="TopicID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("topic") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("topic") %>'>
       </asp:Label>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField DataField="question" HeaderText="Question"  /> 
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The actual implementation depends on what method you're using.

Related issue:

[How to add tooltip to BoundField](https://forums.asp.net/t/1456738.aspx?how%20to%20add%20tool%20tip%20to%20bound%20field)

Answer (score 1):

One hacky way to achieve this is to convert your `BoundField` to `TemplateField` option.

Convert this:

```
<asp:BoundField  DataField="topic"  HeaderText="Topic"  />
```

To this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Topic">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Topic") %>' ToolTip ='<%# Bind("Topic") %>'></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Or From code behind you can do it in `RowDataBound` event like this

```
protected void Dgvlist_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
        }
    }
```